# How to enable C# <see langword="..." /> in doxygen?

Tags: c#, doxygen

When using Doxygen to generate C# documentation, the following XML results in the screenshot below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [handle error].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <see langword="true"/> if [handle error]; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </value>
```

[image: Doxygen html for the XML above]

As you can see, the `<see langword="true"/>` and `<see langword="false"/>` are ignored completely.

**How do I make sure these `<see langword="..."/>` tags are correctly interpreted by Doxygen?** If this is not possible, then is there a way to generate this type of 'ignored' tag literally in the documentation instead of having the page display nothing?